# Ruby Datamapper group by with max

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have a MySQL table:

```
id       int
a        varchar
b        varchar
c        varchar
version  int
active   bool
```

I want to grab the max version group by a, b and c, so I have the following query to do that:

```
select a, b, c, max(version) as version from mytbl where active = 1 group by a, b, c
```

I am using Datamapper with Sinatra. The above table model name is "mytbl".
What would be the datamapper equivalent of the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it :)

```
mytbl.aggregate(:version.max, :active => 1, :fields => [:a, :b, :c], :unique => true, :order => nil)
```

or

```
mytbl.aggregate(:version.max, :conditions => [ 'active = ?', 1], :fields => [:a, :b, :c], :unique => true, :order => nil)
```

However I could not find a way to alias max(version) as version. It returns max(version) as the column name. Thats not a big deal ;)